# min/max of a function without built in operators nor for/while/if?

Tags: matlab

We have to determine the min/max values of a 1x6000 array without using the operators mentionned in the title. We have to use algorithms learned in class, but I don't see how that would translate to matlab, as I will need to do a certain number of iterations before I get the right answer.

We learned the bisection method, muller method, newton method, fixed point method, etc.

Please don't write the code, as this is my homework, and I'm trying to learn something, but if you could guide me in the right direction...

Thank you.

Comment: How do you plan on accomplishing any of those methods without builtin operators or logic control?

Comment: That's my question, please see the algorithms I referred.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to write an *iterative* algorithm without logic control?

Comment: Can you use `sort`? If so, it's easy. Can you use comparisons? If so, `<`-compare each element with each other element and take the element with most / fewest `true` results

Comment: Yeah I'll use sort for now, although I feel like it's cheating. I'll change it up later based on what my teacher says.

Comment: Question - How can you use Newton's method, bisection or any fixed point method if you can't use a `for` or `while` loop?  They're both iterative algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

I'm a bit confused on why you can't use a `for` or `while` loop because Newton's method, the bisection method or any fixed point method is an **iterative** algorithm which requires loops.  As such, this answer assumes that other than using these methods that are using loops, no other loops are allowed.

---

Since you're allowed to use Newton's method or the bisection method, remember that these methods find the root of a function or where the function output is equal to 0.  Also remember that when you find the derivative and see where the values are equal to 0, this tells you what critical points (min and max) are part of the function.  Therefore, if you ran Newton's or the bisection method on the derivative of your function, you would then be able to determine the critical points and hence where the min or max are.  However, these don't tell if you the points are at a minimum or a maximum.  Therefore, you'd have to take a look at the second derivative and examine the sign at these points.  If the sign is positive, it is a minimum and if the sign is negative, it is a maximum.

Because you only have an array of points and not the actual function itself, have a look at [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) which computes the discrete approximation to the derivative (i.e. a finite difference) for an array.  Also when you are specifying points in the array that don't belong to an integer values as it will be inevitable with Newton's or the bisection, have a look at [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to interpolate and find the approximate value in between integer points.

I'll do only the case for Newton's method.  You can derive a similar set of rules for the bisection method. Recall that Newton's method is defined such that:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mit.edu](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/NLAE/equation7.gif))</sub>

`x_i` is the current guess of the root while `x_{i+1}` is the next guess of the root.  `f(x_i)` is the function evaluated at `x_i` while `f'(x_i)` is the derivative of the function.  Since you want to find the critical points where the derivative is equal to 0 and not the original function, `f(x_i)` is now `f'(x_i)` and its derivative is simply the second derivative or `f''(x_i)`.

Given that `X` is the array of points you have, the pseudocode could look something like this:

1. Use `dx = diff(X, 1)` to compute the first derivative and `dx2 = diff(X, 2)` to compute the second derivative.
2. Specify an initial guess of the root, `xp`, of the derivative, or where you think the minimum or maximum point is.  Starting at the halfway point where `xp = floor(numel(X)/2);` may be a good place to start.
3. Run Newton's method `N` amount of times or when the difference between successive guesses of the root is less than some threshold on `diff(X, 1)` using `xp` as the initial guess and updating `xp` to be used for future guesses.  For each guess of the root, use `interp1` to determine the approximate value of the derivative at this point.  Therefore, the Newton's update rule would look something like:

   ```
   i1 = interp1(1:numel(dx), dx, xp, 'linear');
   i2 = interp1(1:numel(dx2), dx2, xp, 'linear');
   xp = xp - (i1 / i2);
   ```

   `i1` is the derivative evaluated at the current guess `xp` while `i2` is the second derivative evaluated at the current guess `xp`.  We then do the update.
4. `xp` will now contain the **location** of where the critical point is.  However, you will probably have floating point precision here so using this to index into your original array `X` to get the minimum or maximum is not valid.  One thing that I can suggest as a heuristic would be to perhaps round `xp` which makes sense because for the decimal floating part of the final root to be `< 0.5` would suggest that you lean towards the left of the value where as going `>= 0.5` would suggest that you lean towards the right.
5. Once Newton's method converges, you need to check if the value is a minimum or maximum.  Since you can't use `if`, a trick here would be to have your function output a two element array where both values are initialized to `NaN`.  Depending on what the sign of the second derivative of this is at `xp`, you can manually create the right index to populate only one element of this array while leaving the other element as `NaN`.  The position that is not `NaN` should tell you if it's a minimum or maximum.  I'll stick with the convention where the first element is a minimum and the second element is a maximum.  You can concretely determine this logic by:

   ```
   minmax = [NaN NaN];
   ind = interp1(1:numel(dx2), dx2, xp, 'linear') > 0 + 1;
   minmax(ind) = X(round(xp));
   ```

   The second statement calculates the index of where we need to populate the value in this array.  It states that if the sign is positive, the value should be equal to 1 and if it isn't, the value should be equal to 0.  Adding an offset of 1 will now mean that the index will either be 1 or 2 where 1 is the minimum value and 2 is the maximum.

---

### What if you have more than one minimum or maximum?

It is possible where you could have more than one minimum or maximum that has the same value over the entire array, or you want to find both the minimum and maximum.  In that case, you'd have to do this recursively where you first run Newton's method to find the minimum and maximum point.  Then you'd have to split up your array into two halves where the first half is the first point in `X` up to this minimum/maximum point and the second half is the minimum/maximum point up to the end.  You'd also have to make the initial guesses the middle of each array to ensure that you're not just going to return the maximum or minimum values possibly being located at the extremities of the array.  If you want to achieve this without a loop, you will have to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science).  If you think about it, this is almost the same as using [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).  I wouldn't be surprised if you could use merge sort's logic in a way that would help you define the minimum and maximum values or specifically use recursion.  However since you stated you can only used fixed-point methods, I didn't suggest to use recursion to begin with.

---

I've given some code hints, but as you said you don't want full code so this should hopefully get you started.  Be advised that there may be some numerical inaccuracies due to `diff` and this is algorithm I haven't tried or tested.  It's an idea that I thought of while reading your question.

Good luck!

Comment: @belgarion No problem.  This was an interesting problem to solve...  however, I would have highly advised to use recursion instead.  It's much easier and if you use it properly, you can get away with doing it without using `if` :).

Comment: In the first lab, teacher asked us not to use loops, i'll ask if it's still valid...